# Magento customer_save_after observer not firing

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer

I have this code, after trying for hours I still cant figure this out.. Custom API works fine but the observer never fires..

I want to fire this observer after an admin edits/saves a customer through admin panel.

local/ghs/ghsapi/etc/api.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ghs_ghsApi>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </ghs_ghsApi>
    </modules>


    <global>
        <models>
            <ghs_ghsapi>
            <class>ghs_ghsApi_Model</class>
            </ghs_ghsapi>
        </models>

        <events>
            <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <fire_delete>
                        <class>ghs_ghsapi/observer</class>
                        <method>observeOrders</method>
                    </fire_delete>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
        </events>
</global>


    <api>
        <resources>
            <ghs translate="title" module="customer">
                <model>ghs_ghsApi_Model_Api</model>
                <title>Customer Resource</title>
                <acl>ghs</acl>
                <methods>
                    <orderlist translate="title" module="customer">
                        <title>Retrieve customer data</title>
                        <acl>ghs/orderlist</acl>
                        <method>orderlist</method>
                    </orderlist>

                    <ordertotal translate="title" module="customer">
                        <title>Retrieve customer data</title>
                        <acl>ghs/ordertotal</acl>
                        <method>ordertotal</method>
                    </ordertotal>


                </methods>
                <faults module="xyz">                   
                </faults>
            </ghs>
        </resources>
    </api>

</config>
```

local/ghs/ghsApi/Model/Observer.php:

```
<?php
class ghs_ghsApi_Model_Observer
{

    public function observeOrders($observer)
    {
       Mage::log('Observer works!');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aris;

**Issue1:** `you have not create  config.xml code and you have put config code at api.xml that is wrong;`
code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Ghs_Ghsapi>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ghs_Ghsapi>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <ghs_ghsapi>
        <class>Ghs_Ghsapi_Helper</class>
      </ghs_ghsapi>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <ghs_ghsapi>
        <class>Ghs_Ghsapi_Model</class>
      </ghs_ghsapi>
    </models>
    <events>
      <adminhtml_customer_save_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <adminhtml_customer_save_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>ghs_ghsapi/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>observeOrders</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </adminhtml_customer_save_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
    </events>
  </global>
```

**Issue2:** folder Name is wrong  should be

Extension name Space: `Ghs`

and Module  is  : `Ghsapi`

That means folder stucure  should be

```
Ghs/Ghsapi/etc/api.xml

Ghs/Ghsapi/etc/config.xml

Ghs/Ghsapi/Model/Observer.php
```

Issue3:api.xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <api>
        <resources>
            <ghs translate="title" module="customer">
                <model>ghs_ghsapi>/api</model>
                <title>Customer Resource</title>
                <acl>ghs</acl>
                <methods>
                    <orderlist translate="title" module="customer">
                        <title>Retrieve customer data</title>
                        <acl>ghs/orderlist</acl>
                        <method>orderlist</method>
                    </orderlist>

                    <ordertotal translate="title" module="customer">
                        <title>Retrieve customer data</title>
                        <acl>ghs/ordertotal</acl>
                        <method>ordertotal</method>
                    </ordertotal>

                </methods>
                <faults module="xyz">                   
                </faults>
            </ghs>
        </resources>
    </api>
```

Comment: Hello Amit, thank you this actually worked. I have few questions:

1. Does config.xml and api.xml need to be separate files? Don't they get merged? 2. Ghs_Ghsapi_Helper, why is this needed?